# Unable to clone from git repository - fatal: unable to update url base from redirection

Tags: git, github, gitlab, repository, clone

I am new to git, when I try to clone using tortoise git into my local folder it says,

```
git.exe clone --progress -v "https://****url****"
Cloning into 'C:\localfolder'...
fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
asked for: https://***url****
redirect: https://code.devops.com/users/sign_in

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you're using the wrong URL.

In this case, the error message is due to the URL you're using causing a redirect of some sort, although the URL to which you've been redirected doesn't support the protocol that Git uses over HTTP.  It looks like that's because it's some sort of HTML sign-in page which Git has no hope of understanding.

You should figure out the correct URL and use it instead, or you should figure out how to provide authentication if you have some sort of proxy  (usually with the `http_proxy` environment variable).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I had updated my Windows account password and needed to refresh git. I used

```
git config --global credential.${remote}.username MY_USER_NAME
git config --global credential.helper store
```

then performed the desired git clone command.  I was then prompted for my new credentials, provided them, and all was well.